problem connecting to Google Big Query from AWS Glue job
As title says, I have a problem connecting to Google Big Query from AWS Glue job. Idea is that I pick up data from database and send it to google big query.
My script looks like this:
import os
import sys
import json
import boto3
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials
from google.auth.external_account import Credentials as ExternalAccountCredentials
from google.auth import load_credentials_from_file
from google.cloud import bigquery
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
import logging

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# AWS Glue Job Arguments
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# AWS S3 setup for credentials
bucket_name = 'aws-glue-assets-123123123-eu-central-1'
credentials_file_key = 'credentials/service-account-impersonation.json'
local_credentials_path = '/tmp/service-account-impersonation.json'
project_id = 'nonprod_project'

# Function to download credentials file from S3
def download_credentials():
    logger.info(f"Downloading credentials from bucket: {bucket_name}, key: {credentials_file_key}")
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=credentials_file_key)
        s3.download_file(bucket_name, credentials_file_key, local_credentials_path)
        logger.info(f"Credentials file downloaded to {local_credentials_path}")
    except boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError as e:
        logger.error(f"Error downloading credentials file: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

# Download credentials
download_credentials()

# Load external account credentials
credentials, project = load_credentials_from_file(local_credentials_path)

# Specify the target service account to impersonate
target_principal = 'myapp@-nonprod.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
target_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

# Create impersonated credentials
impersonated_creds = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
    source_credentials=credentials,
    target_principal=target_principal,
    target_scopes=target_scopes
)

# Refresh the impersonated credentials
request = Request()
impersonated_creds.refresh(request)

# Initialize the BigQuery client
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=impersonated_creds, project=project)

# Define your DynamicFrames
def create_dynamic_frame(table_name):
    return glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="mysql",
        connection_options={
            "useConnectionProperties": "true",
            "dbtable": table_name,
            "connectionName": "myapp nonprod DB",
        },
        transformation_ctx=f"{table_name}_dynamic_frame"
    )

tables = ['changes', 'pull_requests', 'event_change', 'team_members']
dynamic_frames = {table: create_dynamic_frame(table) for table in tables}

# Drop duplicates
def drop_duplicates(frame):
    return DynamicFrame.fromDF(frame.toDF().dropDuplicates(), glueContext, f"{frame.transformation_ctx}_drop_duplicates")

dynamic_frames = {table: drop_duplicates(df) for table, df in dynamic_frames.items()}

# Drop fields for specific tables
drop_fields_frames = {
    'pull_requests': DropFields.apply(frame=dynamic_frames['pull_requests'], paths=["organization_name", "comment_id"], transformation_ctx="pull_requests_drop_fields")
}

# Function to load data to BigQuery
def load_to_bigquery(df, table_id):
    pandas_df = df.toDF().toPandas()
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
    load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(pandas_df, table_id, job_config=job_config)
    load_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete
    logger.info(f"Loaded {load_job.output_rows} rows into {table_id}.")

# Write data to BigQuery
for table, df in dynamic_frames.items():
    table_id = f'change_tracker.{table}'
    load_to_bigquery(df, table_id)

for table, df in drop_fields_frames.items():
    table_id = f'change_tracker.{table}'
    load_to_bigquery(df, table_id)

job.commit()


I have set workload identity federation pool and add service account to it. I'm trying to impersonate service account. My credentials looks like this:
{
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/123455678/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/mynonprodpool/providers/aws-devendi-nonprod",
  "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:aws:token-type:aws4_request",
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/myapp@nonprod.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
  "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
  "credential_source": {
    "environment_id": "aws1",
    "region_url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone",
    "url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials",
    "regional_cred_verification_url": "https://sts.{region}.amazonaws.com?Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15"
  }
}

But when I run the job I get :
Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; RefreshError: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n "error": {\n "code": 403,\n "message": "Permission \'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",\n "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n "details": [\n {\n "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",\n "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",\n "metadata": {\n "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"\n }\n }\n ]\n }\n}\n')
Trusted entities for IAM role in AWS looks like this:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::123123123:oidc-provider/oidc.googleapis.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "oidc.googleapis.com:aud": "aws-devendi-nonprod"
            }
        }
    }
]

}
Also, I have working solution with service account, but I need to replace it with Google Workload Identity federation.
Have anybody experienced similar issue?

Why do you use a service account key file with an external account definition. The STS will try to create a token on the service account. Add the Service Account User role to your service account to allow the token creation

@guillaumeblaquiere I’m not using key file, I’m using file for workload identity federation. And I already added service account user role rk the service account

My bad, the name trick me!! Did you check your permissions on Google Cloud side? The permission to create a token (service account token creator role for insance)

Hi @guillaumeblaquiere no worries, thanks for your answers. Yup, I gave that as well. And still getting the same results
